# Ability to Create Excel Hyperlinks VBA With Pivot Table Event

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

I currently have a Pivot table that has hyperlinks stored in data set. When you double click, the data is static and the hyperlink is just text.

Is there a way with VBA to create an event where when the user clicks on the pivot table it will run a code and convert the text into hyperlinks?

Thanks!

```
Private Sub Workbook_NewSheet(ByVal Sh As Object)
```

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking the answer is no, you cannot insert hyperlinks into a pivot table.

However, there is probably a way to do what you want, but it depends on what your hyperlinks are. Are they links to websites? Is the hyperlink address input directly in the cell, or was it added by right click > insert hyperlink, or =HYPERLINK formula?

The below code may do what you want: if the user clicks on a cell that is in a pivot table and contains "www.", Excel will attempt to open a website based on the text in the cell that has been clicked.

This code must be placed in the ThisWorkbook module.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Excel.Range)

Dim PT As String

On Error Resume Next
    PT = Target.PivotTable.Name
On Error GoTo 0

If PT <> "" Then
    If InStr(Target, "www.") Then
        If Left(Target, 4) = "http" Then
            FollowHyperlink (Target)
        Else
            FollowHyperlink ("https://" & Target)
        End If
    End If
End If

End Sub
```